# How to send value of XML tags

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have an external CMLfile which i have save it in the Xml folder of Asp.Net mvc project i am trying to use the stringwriter to replace the string of the xml file which i have written in square brackets [ ]

```
string lStrXMLRequest = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Xml/SoapAvailabilitySearch.xml");

StreamReader str = new StreamReader(lStrXMLRequest);
string XMLText = str.ReadToEnd();
str.Close();
XMLText.Replace("[orgname]",org);
```

But I saw orgname is not getting replace by the value which is been sent in org variable. Could any one please tell me how to send value from c# to the XML file.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <AvailabilitySearch xmlns="http://www.reservwire.com/namespace/WebServices/Xml">
      <xiRequest>
        <Authority>
          <Org>[orgname]</Org>
          </Authority>
          </xiRequest>
    </AvailabilitySearch>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: this will replace the file contents with new string `string xml = File.ReadAllText(lStrXMLRequest); File.WriteAllText(lStrXMLRequest, xml.Replace("[orgname]", org));`

Answer (score 0):

You have written an XML file, but one of the fields is not correct, so rather than correcting that field before writing it, you decide that loading it as a text  into memory, and doing a string replace is a good idea?

What if that file is 100MB or 10GB?  You might struggle to load that into memory just to do a string replace !

Why not just fix the file in the first place?

Comment: i have corrected the xml now . If replace is not a good idea then what would be the ideal approach to send value from c# to xml file in [orgname]

Comment: How is the XML file being created in the first place?

Comment: i have mentioned in the question that i have an .xml file in the xml folder of my project. i already have the xml file just the values inside the tags will be dynamic so how do i send values from c# to the tags

Comment: So, this is not really a question about XML, it's a question about how to replace a tag in a text file?

Answer (score 0):

Your original attempt is not using `string.Replace` correctly. Strings are immutable, so this method returns a new string with the old text replaced by the new text. Your code doesn't assign it to anything, so it's thrown away when the method completes.

This will work for your needs but is not memory-efficient because you would have to read the entire file into memory to perform the replacement.

An alternative would be to use [XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx) and XmlWriter to read nodes one at a time from the file with a reader and passing them to a writer, conditionally writing the updated element value where it is found in the node sequence.

Answer (score 0):

The xml has a namespace which must be handled properly.  He is one way of changing value using Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string lStrXMLRequest = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(lStrXMLRequest);


            XElement ord = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Org").FirstOrDefault();

            ord.SetValue("abc");

        }
    }
}
```